# Use Registry value to start a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, conditional-statements

I'd like to check at fixed time intervals (days) if a specific registry key exceeds a certain value.
If yes, then run a batchfile.
Is this possible (maybe with RegScanner ?) / how ?

thx

Comment: you are looking for task scheduler

Comment: Schedule a task with `reg query` and consecutive `if ... call yourbatch.bat` in a simple batch file. Reference: [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)

Answer (score 0):

This is from the sample code in Help on **RegistryValueChangeEvent** in WMI

```
Set wmiServices = GetObject("winmgmts:root/default") 
Set wmiSink = WScript.CreateObject( _
    "WbemScripting.SWbemSink", "SINK_") 
wmiServices.ExecNotificationQueryAsync wmiSink, _ 
    "SELECT * FROM RegistryValueChangeEvent " _
    & "WHERE Hive='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' AND " _
    & "KeyPath='SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\WBEM\\sCRIPTING' " _
    & "AND ValueName='Default Namespace'" 
WScript.Echo "Listening for Registry Value" _
    & " Change Events..." & vbCrLf 
While(True) 
    WScript.Sleep 1000 
Wend 
Sub SINK_OnObjectReady(wmiObject, wmiAsyncContext) 
    WScript.Echo "Received Registry " _
        & "Change Event" & vbCrLf & _ 
        wmiObject.GetObjectText_() 
End Sub
```